# Foreign Key with Compound Keys vs Auto Increment

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database in which I will store conversations between two users. I will hold a conversations table along with a messages table. Conversations table will store conversations between two users and messages table will store the messages in a specific conversation. There will be only one conversation between two users like MSN messenger or Facebook messages and new messages will be added into this conversation. I have two ideas to do this.

First approach:

```
conversations(c_id, user1, user2)
```

c_id is primary key auto_incremented

```
messages(m_id, c_id, user_from, user_to, content)
```

m_id is primary key auto_incremented, c_id is foreign key references conversations(c_id)

In the second approach,

```
conversations(user1, user2)
```

(user1, user2) is compound primary key

```
messages(m_id, user_from, user_to, content)
```

m_id is primary key, (user_from, user_to) is foreign key references conversations(user1, user2)

My question is which one of these is better? 1st, 2nd or none? I haven't use compound foreign keys in any of my designs yet, and honestly I don't know what the outcome would be.

*Apart from all of these fields there will be read date, enter date etc. fields. For sake of brevity I am skipping those.*

Comment: I don't see what the `conversations` table is buying you here. Why not just `message (m_id, from_user_id, to_user_id, content)`?

Comment: Actually for 2 reasons,
First one I want to show all conversations of a user in a list view so he can choose it from this list to see messages. By keeping 2 separate tables I can do this faster, I guess. Second one, users might delete their messages in the future and I don't want to lose conversations

Comment: To get the compound key to work you will need two conversations for each pair, one from user 1 to user 2 and vice versa. Or add a direction column to conversation, and call them user1, user2 instead.

Comment: Thank you for the direction approach, storing 1 byte instead of 2*4 more efficient at the end

Answer (score 0):

Keys/index decision are heavily influenced by how you will query the data. I'm going to ignore insert performance, assuming that your query performance is much more important (which could be wrong assumption, only you know that). Also, based on your column names, I'm assuming message direction is important, as in within the same conversation, sometimes user X is in the messages user_from column, and sometimes is in the user_to column. In your comment to Laurence, you said you will first display a list of conversations that a user has taken part in, and then when they click on one, you will show the list of messages. So we probably aren't looking at a join, but instead a pair of queries since you will only get messages for one conversation at a time.

Query 1 will be a selection on conversations for user X, something like:
select * from conversations where user1 = X or user2 = X

At this point, both options are equivalent. Now, the second query gets the messages for a given conversation.

option 1:
select * from message where c_id = ?  (c_id fetched in first query, and you associated it with each row in your listbox)

option 2:
from the listbox click, you now know you want the messages for the conversation between users X and Y:

select * from messages where (user_from = X and user_to = Y) OR (user_from = Y and user_to = X)

If all my assumptions that lead me here are correct, then clearly option 1 is superior, as it's a very fast single valued primary key lookup. Otherwise, do a similar analysis of how you will query the data, which should point to the better solution.

(as an aside, in your messages table, instead of repeating the two users, just have a 0/1 bit column indicating the direction of the conversation, since the conversation table already has an order. e.g. if conversation table has cid 1, user X, user Y, then the messages table for cid 1 can have a bit set to zero when user x is the from user, and a bit set to 1 when user y is the from user)

Answer (score 0):

My personal preference is to never have composite FKs -- if there is a one-to-many relationship between a table with a composite PK and another table, as a rule of thumb I create a single column primary key (auto-increment, concatenating the existing columns or whichever method of unique key generation cuts it for you) and then key on that.  I think composite FKs are simply too messy to conceive in visualizing the relationship between two tables.

YMMV